# How to use @media?

Tags: css

i want to turn my website responsive.

I heard about media@ i already did some stuff on my code

```
@media all  and (min-width: 310px) and (max-width: 1000px) {

.subitem{
margin-left: -80px;
text-align: left;
}


.mitem{
height: 13%;

}



.mname{
text-align:center;
 margin: 5%;
}

@media all  and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width:845px) {

.subitem{
display:none;
}

.mname{
display:none;
}



}
```

When i resize my website on my browser, it works perfectly, but i tried to acess my website on my mobile phone and it doesn't work.

Probably is because i'm not doing it well, i need some demonstration...

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: If this is exactly as-is, you're missing a closing brace (`}`) before the second `@media` query. That's not helping. Definitely check the above link, though - lack of a viewport is very likely the main problem.

Comment: Thanks Paul, it was my fault, thank you.